# Installation issue

Tags: visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

starting a new project and wanted to play with the new MVC 4 beta.

when i install i from the web platform installer i get this log error...

```
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Install exit code for product 'ASP.NET MVC 4 Installer (Visual Studio 2010)' is -2114715647
DownloadManager Error: 0 : Install return code for product 'ASP.NET MVC 4 Installer (Visual Studio 2010)' is Failure
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Product ASP.NET MVC 4 Installer (Visual Studio 2010) done install completed
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Increasing current install to 2
```

reading about this issue, there seems to be alot of people with the same problem but no consistant solution.

Comment: Better download the offline installer and install it.

Comment: did you install VS2010 Service Pack 1?

Comment: yes i have SP1 installed

Comment: you can download the stand alone installer here -> http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=27419

Answer (score 0):

This is potentially an antivirus issue. The install was failing for me too, and as it turned out, a McAfee access protection rule was blocking the installation from completing. The rule was called "Prevent programs registering to autorun". My LAN administrator turned off that rule temporarily, and the install succeeded.