# MVC 4 installation failure

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am attempting to install MVC 4 to my desktop.  I am the only person in the office whop is having this problem even though we all have the same machines with the same software.  I'm not sure what the problem is.  The installation prints a log file but I don't know what any of it means.  If anyone has an answer I would appreciate it.  Here is the log file:

```
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Loading product xml from: https://go.microsoft.com/?linkid=9810537
DownloadManager Information: 0 : https://go.microsoft.com/?linkid=9810537 responded with 302
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Response headers:
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Cache-Control: private
Content-Length: 175
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Expires: Fri, 17 Aug 2012 17:13:22 GMT
Location: https://www.microsoft.com/web/webpi/4.0/webproductlist.xml
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-AspNet-Version: 2.0.50727
Set-Cookie: MC1=GUID=c6f89ed006465f41bf8ce6e310c073fb&HASH=d09e&LV=20128&V=3;    domain=microsoft.com; expires=Sun, 03-Oct-2010 07:00:00 GMT; path=/
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Fri, 17 Aug 2012 17:14:22 GMT


DownloadManager Information: 0 : https://www.microsoft.com/web/webpi/4.0/webproductlist.xml responded with 304
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Response headers:
HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified
Cache-Control: max-age=900
Accept-Ranges: bytes
ETag: "d77eb3a9227bcd1:0"
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
P3P: CP="ALL IND DSP COR ADM CONo CUR CUSo IVAo IVDo PSA PSD TAI TELo OUR SAMo CNT COM INT NAV ONL PHY PRE PUR UNI"
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
X-Powered-By: ARR/2.5
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Fri, 17 Aug 2012 17:14:21 GMT


DownloadManager Information: 0 : Remote file has not changed, using local cached file: C:\Users\ppprog6202\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\-477760839.xml.temp
DownloadManager Warning: 0 : Could not resolve keyword ID Sharepoint
DownloadManager Warning: 0 : Could not resolve keyword ID Office
DownloadManager Warning: 0 : Could not resolve keyword ID Sharepoint
DownloadManager Warning: 0 : Could not resolve keyword ID Office
DownloadManager Warning: 0 : Could not resolve keyword ID SQL
DownloadManager Warning: 0 : Could not resolve keyword ID SQL
DownloadManager Warning: 0 : Could not resolve keyword ID WIF
DownloadManager Warning: 0 : Could not resolve keyword ID identity
DownloadManager Warning: 0 : Could not resolve keyword ID federation
DownloadManager Warning: 0 : Could not resolve keyword ID claims
DownloadManager Warning: 0 : Could not resolve keyword ID authentication
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Filtering by majorOS: 6, minorOS: 1, majorSP: 1, minorSP: 0, productType: 6, architecture: x64
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Loading product xml from: https://www.microsoft.com/web/webpi/4.0/webapplicationlist.xml
DownloadManager Information: 0 : https://www.microsoft.com/web/webpi/4.0/webapplicationlist.xml responded with 304
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Response headers:
HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified
Cache-Control: max-age=900
Accept-Ranges: bytes
ETag: "43da3ca8137bcd1:0"
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
P3P: CP="ALL IND DSP COR ADM CONo CUR CUSo IVAo IVDo PSA PSD TAI TELo OUR SAMo CNT COM INT NAV ONL PHY PRE PUR UNI"
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
X-Powered-By: ARR/2.5
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Fri, 17 Aug 2012 17:14:22 GMT


DownloadManager Information: 0 : Remote file has not changed, using local cached file: C:\Users\ppprog6202\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\251486345.xml.temp
DownloadManager Warning: 0 : Could not resolve keyword ID Katalready
DownloadManager Warning: 0 : Could not resolve keyword ID Katalready
DownloadManager Warning: 0 : Could not resolve keyword ID ApplicationSpotlight
DownloadManager Warning: 0 : Could not resolve keyword ID ApplicationSpotlight
DownloadManager Warning: 0 : Could not resolve keyword ID ApplicationSpotlight
DownloadManager Warning: 0 : Could not resolve keyword ID ApplicationSpotlight
DownloadManager Warning: 0 : Could not resolve keyword ID ApplicationSpotlight
DownloadManager Warning: 0 : Could not resolve keyword ID ApplicationSpotlight
DownloadManager Warning: 0 : Could not resolve keyword ID ApplicationSpotlight
DownloadManager Warning: 0 : Could not resolve keyword ID ApplicationSpotlight
DownloadManager Warning: 0 : Could not resolve keyword ID ApplicationSpotlight
DownloadManager Warning: 0 : Could not resolve keyword ID ApplicationSpotlight
DownloadManager Warning: 0 : Could not resolve keyword ID ApplicationSpotlight
DownloadManager Warning: 0 : Could not resolve keyword ID Katalready
DownloadManager Warning: 0 : Could not resolve keyword ID ApplicationSpotlight
DownloadManager Warning: 0 : Could not resolve keyword ID Katalready
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Filtering by majorOS: 6, minorOS: 1, majorSP: 1, minorSP: 0, productType: 6, architecture: x64
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Loading product xml from: https://www.microsoft.com/web/webpi/4.0/mediaproductlist.xml
DownloadManager Information: 0 : https://www.microsoft.com/web/webpi/4.0/mediaproductlist.xml responded with 304
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Response headers:
HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified
Date: Fri, 17 Aug 2012 17:14:22 GMT
Etag: "1b51c01e6f4ecd1:0"
Cache-Control: max-age=900


DownloadManager Information: 0 : Remote file has not changed, using local cached file: C:\Users\ppprog6202\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\598799360.xml.temp
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Filtering by majorOS: 6, minorOS: 1, majorSP: 1, minorSP: 0, productType: 6, architecture: x64
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Loading product xml from: https://www.microsoft.com/web/webpi/4.0/toolsproductlist.xml
DownloadManager Information: 0 : https://www.microsoft.com/web/webpi/4.0/toolsproductlist.xml responded with 304
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Response headers:
HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified
Date: Fri, 17 Aug 2012 17:14:22 GMT
Etag: "4e6536ff8276cd1:0"
Cache-Control: max-age=900


DownloadManager Information: 0 : Remote file has not changed, using local cached file: C:\Users\ppprog6202\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\672503665.xml.temp
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Filtering by majorOS: 6, minorOS: 1, majorSP: 1, minorSP: 0, productType: 6, architecture: x64
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Loading product xml from: https://www.microsoft.com/web/webpi/4.0/enterpriseproductlist.xml
DownloadManager Information: 0 : https://www.microsoft.com/web/webpi/4.0/enterpriseproductlist.xml responded with 304
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Response headers:
HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified
Date: Fri, 17 Aug 2012 17:14:22 GMT
Etag: "a68a64382f88cc1:0"
Cache-Control: max-age=900


DownloadManager Information: 0 : Remote file has not changed, using local cached file: C:\Users\ppprog6202\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\1505006577.xml.temp
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Filtering by majorOS: 6, minorOS: 1, majorSP: 1, minorSP: 0, productType: 6, architecture: x64
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Getting ratings file from http://go.microsoft.com/?linkid=9752395
DownloadManager Information: 0 : http://go.microsoft.com/?linkid=9752395 responded with 302
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Response headers:
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Cache-Control: private
Content-Length: 203
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Expires: Fri, 17 Aug 2012 17:13:24 GMT
Location: http://www.microsoft.com/web/handlers /WebPI.ashx?command=getatomfeedwithavgratingquery
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-AspNet-Version: 2.0.50727
Set-Cookie: MC1=GUID=5dcd22f7d0af19428d827c6bc0604293&HASH=f722&LV=20128&V=3; domain=microsoft.com; expires=Sun, 03-Oct-2010 07:00:00 GMT; path=/
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Fri, 17 Aug 2012 17:14:24 GMT


DownloadManager Information: 0 : Contextual entry products: MVC4VS2010
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Adding product ASP.NET MVC 4 (VS 2010) (MVC4VS2010) to cart
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Contextual navigation to product 'MVC4VS2010'
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Ratings file loaded successfully
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Adding product 'MVC4VS2010'
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Adding dependency product 'MVC4VS2010_Only
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Setting current install to 1
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Starting install sequence
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Downloading file 'http://download.microsoft.com/download/2/F/6/2F63CCD8-9288-4CC8-B58C-81D109F8F5A3/AspNetMVC4Setup.exe' to: C:\Users\ppprog6202\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp6948.tmp
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Content-disposition header: attachment
DownloadManager Information: 0 : File 'C:\Users\ppprog6202\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\installers\MVC4VS2010_Only\F46B534A9D488ABEC38EFB67571F52B4A6FC43E3\AspNetMVC4Setup.exe' already exists, deleting old copy of the file
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Moving downloaded file 'C:\Users\ppprog6202\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp6948.tmp' to: C:\Users\ppprog6202\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\installers\MVC4VS2010_Only\F46B534A9D488ABEC38EFB67571F52B4A6FC43E3\AspNetMVC4Setup.exe
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Starting EXE command for product 'ASP.NET MVC 4 Installer (VS 2010)- Default Locale'. Commandline is: 'C:\Users\ppprog6202\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\installers\MVC4VS2010_Only\F46B534A9D488ABEC38EFB67571F52B4A6FC43E3\AspNetMVC4Setup.exe /q /log C:\Users\PPPROG~1\AppData\Local\Temp\MVC4VS2010_Only_install.htm'. Process Id: 3676
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Install exit code for product 'ASP.NET MVC 4  Installer (VS 2010)- Default Locale' is -2147023254
DownloadManager Error: 0 : Install return code for product 'ASP.NET MVC 4 Installer (VS 2010)- Default Locale' is Failure
DownloadManager Warning: 0 : Dependency failed for product 'ASP.NET MVC 4 (VS 2010)'. Skipping install
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Product ASP.NET MVC 4 Installer (VS 2010)- Default Locale done install completed
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Increasing current install to 2
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Product ASP.NET MVC 4 (VS 2010) had a dependency fail. Increasing install product to 3
```

Comment: Try the answer given for this link
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9583396/error-installing-asp-net-mvc-4

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The WebPI could suck sometimes (for me always).

I'd recommend you to download and install the MSI yourself:

- [ASP.NET MVC 4 for Visual Studio 2010 SP1 and Visual Web Developer 2010 SP1](http://www.microsoft.com/download/details.aspx?id=30683)

Make sure that you have installed SP1 for VS2010 before though.

Comment: Did this work for you. We are getting the exact same error message but downloading the entire MSI does not fix the problem. It still error's out but we can't view the log when using the MSI.

Comment: I cancelled the installation from the MSI once, and now it fails everytime with "user cancelled installation" - not sure what to do...

Comment: this doesn't work for me either, did anyone in the past who were stuck ever get this resolved?

Answer (score 4):

After waiting more than 10 minutes for step 2 to complete, I decided to do a google search. For "asp.net mvc 4 installer" google suggested "asp.net mvc 4 installer hangs".
While I was reading this thread, the installer continued to step 3. So I am suggesting to wait about half an hour.

Comment: I let it go overnight while it was stuck at step 2.... still at step 2 this morning. I'm downloading directly, skipping WebPI (4.5). What a joke, a tool specifically for installing a few programs, can't even manage to get that right. I love quality software.

Answer (score 0):

I've got this problem.

webpi seemed to have got stuck so I cancelled it. I tried running the installer directly: http://download.microsoft.com/download/2/F/6/2F63CCD8-9288-4CC8-B58C-81D109F8F5A3/AspNetMVC4Setup.exe

I got an error:

```
Install completed (Failure): 'ASP.NET MVC 4 Installer (VS 2010)- Default Locale'
MVC4VS2010_Only : Failed.

DependencyFailed: ASP.NET MVC 4 Language Packs Installer
DependencyFailed: ASP.NET MVC 4 with Language Packs (August 2012)

Verifying successful installation...
ASP.NET MVC 4 Installer (VS 2010)- Default Locale  False
ASP.NET MVC 4 Language Packs Installer             False
ASP.NET MVC 4 with Language Packs (August 2012)    False
Install of Products: FAILURE
```

so i decided to run the installer manually:

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=3556

and got this error:

```
0x80070652 - Another installation is already in progress. Complete that installation before proceeding with this install.
```

although there was a link to the log file I couldn't open it.

Looking process explorer (sysinternals), I can see this update being installed: 
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=3556

So i expect when that's installed I'll be able to run the installer again. Will let everyone know.

Comment: The GUI based install worked. I'm going to try uninstalling and installing through webpi again

Comment: Having uninstalled, webpi worked fine from the command line. It's pretty clear to me that sometimes webpi has to download and install updates in the background. It doesn't make this very clear on the console which makes you think it's stalled.