# MVC 4 Installation Failure - Offline or with web installer

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am attempting to install MVC 4 into Visual Studio 2010 but it keeps failing with both the web installer and the offline installer.

I have tried the items mentioned in this question "[MVC 4 installation failure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12011496/mvc-4-installation-failure)" but to no avail.

The error with the web installer is as follows:

```
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Loading product xml from: https://go.microsoft.com/?linkid=9824573
DownloadManager Information: 0 : https://go.microsoft.com/?linkid=9824573 responded with 302
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Response headers:
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Cache-Control: private
Content-Length: 175
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Expires: Thu, 21 Nov 2013 20:05:20 GMT
Location: https://www.microsoft.com/web/webpi/4.6/webproductlist.xml
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-AspNet-Version: 2.0.50727
Set-Cookie: MC1=GUID=********&V=3; domain=microsoft.com; expires=Sun, 03-Oct-2010 07:00:00 GMT; path=/
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Thu, 21 Nov 2013 20:06:20 GMT


DownloadManager Information: 0 : https://www.microsoft.com/web/webpi/4.6/webproductlist.xml responded with 304
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Response headers:
HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified
Cache-Control: max-age=900
Accept-Ranges: bytes
ETag: "46991ac784e4ce1:0"
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.0
P3P: CP="ALL IND DSP COR ADM CONo CUR CUSo IVAo IVDo PSA PSD TAI TELo OUR SAMo CNT COM INT NAV ONL PHY PRE PUR UNI"
VTag: 791225631700000000
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
X-Powered-By: ARR/2.5
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Thu, 21 Nov 2013 20:06:20 GMT


DownloadManager Information: 0 : Remote file has not changed, using local cached file: C:\Users\********\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\-872341423.xml.temp
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Filtering by majorOS: 6, minorOS: 1, majorSP: 1, minorSP: 0, productType: 6, architecture: x64
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Loading product xml from: https://www.microsoft.com/web/webpi/4.6/webapplicationlist.xml
DownloadManager Information: 0 : https://www.microsoft.com/web/webpi/4.6/webapplicationlist.xml responded with 304
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Response headers:
HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified
Cache-Control: max-age=900
Accept-Ranges: bytes
ETag: "49f9d365cde0ce1:0"
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.0
P3P: CP="ALL IND DSP COR ADM CONo CUR CUSo IVAo IVDo PSA PSD TAI TELo OUR SAMo CNT COM INT NAV ONL PHY PRE PUR UNI"
VTag: 791225631700000000
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
X-Powered-By: ARR/2.5
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Thu, 21 Nov 2013 20:06:22 GMT


DownloadManager Information: 0 : Remote file has not changed, using local cached file: C:\Users\********\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\751837351.xml.temp
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Filtering by majorOS: 6, minorOS: 1, majorSP: 1, minorSP: 0, productType: 6, architecture: x64
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Sucessfully loaded the feed 'https://www.microsoft.com/web/webpi/4.6/webapplicationlist.xml' after preprocessing, location on disk: 'C:\Users\********\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\preprocessor\751837351.xml'
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Loading product xml from: https://www.microsoft.com/web/webpi/4.6/mediaproductlist.xml
DownloadManager Information: 0 : https://www.microsoft.com/web/webpi/4.6/mediaproductlist.xml responded with 304
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Response headers:
HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified
Cache-Control: max-age=900
Accept-Ranges: bytes
ETag: "0bfe8cc116dce1:0"
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.0
P3P: CP="ALL IND DSP COR ADM CONo CUR CUSo IVAo IVDo PSA PSD TAI TELo OUR SAMo CNT COM INT NAV ONL PHY PRE PUR UNI"
VTag: 279888730500000000
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
X-Powered-By: ARR/2.5
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Thu, 21 Nov 2013 20:06:22 GMT


DownloadManager Information: 0 : Remote file has not changed, using local cached file: C:\Users\********\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\1953942818.xml.temp
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Filtering by majorOS: 6, minorOS: 1, majorSP: 1, minorSP: 0, productType: 6, architecture: x64
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Sucessfully loaded the feed 'https://www.microsoft.com/web/webpi/4.6/mediaproductlist.xml' after preprocessing, location on disk: 'C:\Users\********\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\preprocessor\1953942818.xml'
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Loading product xml from: https://www.microsoft.com/web/webpi/4.6/ToolsProductList.xml
DownloadManager Information: 0 : https://www.microsoft.com/web/webpi/4.6/ToolsProductList.xml responded with 304
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Response headers:
HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified
Cache-Control: max-age=900
Accept-Ranges: bytes
ETag: "3454204a6ee1ce1:0"
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.0
P3P: CP="ALL IND DSP COR ADM CONo CUR CUSo IVAo IVDo PSA PSD TAI TELo OUR SAMo CNT COM INT NAV ONL PHY PRE PUR UNI"
VTag: 438595230500000000
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
X-Powered-By: ARR/2.5
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Thu, 21 Nov 2013 20:06:22 GMT


DownloadManager Information: 0 : Remote file has not changed, using local cached file: C:\Users\********\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\-95717523.xml.temp
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Filtering by majorOS: 6, minorOS: 1, majorSP: 1, minorSP: 0, productType: 6, architecture: x64
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Sucessfully loaded the feed 'https://www.microsoft.com/web/webpi/4.6/ToolsProductList.xml' after preprocessing, location on disk: 'C:\Users\********\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\preprocessor\-95717523.xml'
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Loading product xml from: https://www.microsoft.com/web/webpi/4.6/enterpriseproductlist.xml
DownloadManager Information: 0 : https://www.microsoft.com/web/webpi/4.6/enterpriseproductlist.xml responded with 304
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Response headers:
HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified
Cache-Control: max-age=900
Accept-Ranges: bytes
ETag: "a744a9fbddace1:0"
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.0
P3P: CP="ALL IND DSP COR ADM CONo CUR CUSo IVAo IVDo PSA PSD TAI TELo OUR SAMo CNT COM INT NAV ONL PHY PRE PUR UNI"
VTag: 438811431600000000
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
X-Powered-By: ARR/2.5
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Thu, 21 Nov 2013 20:06:22 GMT


DownloadManager Information: 0 : Remote file has not changed, using local cached file: C:\Users\********\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\-1709116680.xml.temp
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Filtering by majorOS: 6, minorOS: 1, majorSP: 1, minorSP: 0, productType: 6, architecture: x64
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Sucessfully loaded the feed 'https://www.microsoft.com/web/webpi/4.6/enterpriseproductlist.xml' after preprocessing, location on disk: 'C:\Users\********\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\preprocessor\-1709116680.xml'
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Sucessfully loaded the feed 'https://go.microsoft.com/?linkid=9824573' after preprocessing, location on disk: 'C:\Users\********\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\preprocessor\-872341423.xml'
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Getting ratings file from http://go.microsoft.com/?linkid=9752395
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Contextual entry products: MVC4VS2010_Loc
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Adding product ASP.NET MVC 4 with Language Packs (August 2012) (MVC4Vs2010_Loc) to cart
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Contextual navigation to product 'MVC4Vs2010_Loc'
DownloadManager Information: 0 : http://go.microsoft.com/?linkid=9752395 responded with 302
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Response headers:
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Cache-Control: private
Content-Length: 203
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Expires: Thu, 21 Nov 2013 20:05:24 GMT
Location: http://www.microsoft.com/web/handlers/WebPI.ashx?command=getatomfeedwithavgratingquery
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-AspNet-Version: 2.0.50727
Set-Cookie: MC1=GUID=********&V=3; domain=microsoft.com; expires=Sun, 03-Oct-2010 07:00:00 GMT; path=/
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Thu, 21 Nov 2013 20:06:24 GMT


DownloadManager Information: 0 : Content-Encoding header: 'gzip'
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Number of bytes downloaded over the internet: '21363'
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Number of bytes after possible decompression: '71682'
DownloadManager Warning: 0 : Error getting last-modified header, error code: 12150
DownloadManager Warning: 0 : HttpQueryInfoWithRetry for HTTP_QUERY_LAST_MODIFIED failed.
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Ratings file loaded successfully
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Adding product 'MVC4Vs2010_Loc'
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Adding dependency product 'MVC4Vs2010_Loc_Only
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Adding dependency product 'MVC4VS2010_Only
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Setting current install to 1
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Starting install sequence
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Downloading file 'http://download.microsoft.com/download/2/F/6/2F63CCD8-9288-4CC8-B58C-81D109F8F5A3/AspNetMVC4Setup.exe' to: H:\TEMP\tmp3847.tmp
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Content-disposition header: attachment
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Number of bytes downloaded over the internet: '37684848'
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Number of bytes after possible decompression: '37684848'
DownloadManager Information: 0 : File 'C:\Users\********\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\installers\MVC4VS2010_Only\82BCBAE192F8CB875C814821A536C959F85D4727\AspNetMVC4Setup.exe' already exists, deleting old copy of the file
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Moving downloaded file 'H:\TEMP\tmp3847.tmp' to: C:\Users\********\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\installers\MVC4VS2010_Only\82BCBAE192F8CB875C814821A536C959F85D4727\AspNetMVC4Setup.exe
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Starting EXE command for product 'ASP.NET MVC 4 Installer (VS 2010)- Default Locale'. Commandline is: 'C:\Users\********\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\installers\MVC4VS2010_Only\82BCBAE192F8CB875C814821A536C959F85D4727\AspNetMVC4Setup.exe /q /log H:\TEMP\MVC4VS2010_Only_install.htm'. Process Id: 2192
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Install exit code for product 'ASP.NET MVC 4 Installer (VS 2010)- Default Locale' is '-2147023293'
DownloadManager Error: 0 : Install return code for product 'ASP.NET MVC 4 Installer (VS 2010)- Default Locale' is Failure
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Product ASP.NET MVC 4 Installer (VS 2010)- Default Locale done install completed
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Increasing current install to 2
DownloadManager Warning: 0 : Dependency failed for product 'ASP.NET MVC 4 Language Packs Installer'. Skipping install
DownloadManager Warning: 0 : Dependency failed for product 'ASP.NET MVC 4 with Language Packs (August 2012)'. Skipping install
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Product ASP.NET MVC 4 Language Packs Installer had a dependency fail. Increasing install product to 3
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Product ASP.NET MVC 4 with Language Packs (August 2012) had a dependency fail. Increasing install product to 4
```

This is on Windows 7 64 bit. If I try with the offline installer I get `Setup Failed` `One or more issues caused the setup to fail. Please fix the issues and then retry setup. For more information see the log file.`. However the `log file` link doesn't go anywhere when clicked.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

After trying [@Jacques Eloff's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20137608/413180) I examined the log file and found the following entry:

```
[2024:21C8][2013-11-22T08:47:22]: Applying execute package: VS10SP1_KB2591016_x86.exe, action: Install, path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\5BA5217D49F8BECD7CA452F2F366CD7C99FF1F16\VS10SP1-KB2591016-x86.exe, arguments: '"C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\5BA5217D49F8BECD7CA452F2F366CD7C99FF1F16\VS10SP1-KB2591016-x86.exe" /q /norestart'
[2024:21C8][2013-11-22T08:47:40]: Error 0x80070643: Process returned error: 0x643
```

I then downloaded the hotfix [KB2591016](http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=29985) manually and attempted installation. This time it prompted me for the VS Ultimate installation disc. After downloading and mounting the image linked from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8894857/413180), installation of KB2591016 succeeded and then I could proceed to successfully install MVC 4.

Comment: I did all of this, and it worked great for me. Thanks for walking it out.

Comment: Created iso file and mounted it. Ran the hotfix no prompt it found the file it needed in the mounted drive and the hot fix is applied with success. I was then ableto run the MVC 4 setup without error.

Comment: The only solution I could find online that actually worked. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

I'd suggest the following:

1. Make sure you have SP1 for Visual Studio 2010 installed. MVC 4 for VS 2010 depends on this since it installs multiple patches for SP1, [one](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/Downloads/DownloadDetails.aspx?DownloadID=38654) of which allows the NuGet MSI to install the NuGet extension in Visual Studio. Even though you may have updated NuGet directly through the VS Gallery, the EXE will still try to run the NuGet MSI.
2. Open Control Panel and go to Installed Programs. Search for an entry that either says **NuGet** or **Microsoft NuGet for Visual Studio 2010** and uninstall it. This won't actually remove NuGet from Visual Studio, it's just the MSI that contained NuGet that would be removed -- the extension will remain installed.
3. Download the standalone MVC 4 installer from http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30683 and run it. The installer will create a number of log files in your %temp% folder. There will be a log file for the EXE, as well as each MSI it installs, including the hotfix EXE I mentioned in #1. All the log files should be prefixed with **dd_AspNetMvc4_**
4. Another point of failure might be the Web Pages 2 runtime MSI that the installer carries. The MSI will try to modify your root web.config file. It should be easy to determine whether this is the point of failure:

   - The EXE log will show that the Web Pages 2 MSI failed, likely with a return code of 1603
   - The MSI log will show a more detailed error.

Comment: Thanks. I tried (2) and (3) helped me find the log file when it failed again.

Answer (score 0):

A combination of SilverlightFox's and Jacques Eloff's answers worked for me. The steps I followed were:

1. First check for Windows Updates and install them if any exist. I had some.
2. Make sure you have SP1 for Visual Studio 2010 installed
3. **Unistall** ASP.NET Web Pages 2
4. **Unistall** NuGet or Microsoft NuGet for Visual Studio 2010
5. Download and mount the .ISO image Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate linked from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8894654/vs-2010-trial-version-link/8894857#8894857)
6. Download the hotfix [KB2591016](http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=29985) manually. It prompted for the VS Ultimate installation disc (that's why I did step 5)
7. Download Web Platform Installer 5 (last edition)
8. Restart computer.
9. Begin installation of framework **ASP.NET MVC 4 with Language Packs (August 2012)** from WebPI.

Hope this help others with the same annoying problem. I also unistalled my Kaspersky antivirus and enabled Windows firewall during this procedure.